# Not able to scan a QR Code from a blob URL

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, blob, qr-code

After searching Google and SO for hours and hours, I couldn't come up with a solution as to how I can scan a QR code in my Java based Selenium tests. I will list out the things that I have tried and the errors that I got.

1. Using the ZXing library. This library doesn't seem to work at all for blob URLs.

   ```
   private String decodeQRCode(URL qrCodeImage) throws IOException, NotFoundException {
       BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(qrCodeImage);
       LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(bufferedImage);
       BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

       Result result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap);
       return result.getText(); 
   }
   ```

Error on trying this:

```
unknown protocol: blob
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: blob
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:617)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:507)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:456)
```

2. Using ZXing library but with Base64 instead of URL.

   ```
   private String decodeQRCode(String qrCodeImage) throws IOException, NotFoundException {
       byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(qrCodeImage);
       BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded));
       LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(bufferedImage);
       BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

       Result result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap);
       return result.getText();
   }
   ```

Error on using this:

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource.<init>(BufferedImageLuminanceSource.java:42)
```

3. Tried the above two methods but this time by removing 'blob:' from the start of the URL and still got the NullPointerException as in the above case.
4. Also tried Javascript injection by using the executeAsyncScript() function.

   ```
   private String getBytesBase64FromBlobURI(String uri) {
       String script = " "
            + "var uri = arguments[0];"
            + "var callback = arguments[1];"
            + "var toBase64 = function(buffer){for(var r,n=new Uint8Array(buffer),t=n.length,a=new Uint8Array(4*Math.ceil(t/3)),i=new Uint8Array(64),o=0,c=0;64>c;++c)i[c]='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'.charCodeAt(c);for(c=0;t-t%3>c;c+=3,o+=4)r=n[c]<<16|n[c+1]<<8|n[c+2],a[o]=i[r>>18],a[o+1]=i[r>>12&63],a[o+2]=i[r>>6&63],a[o+3]=i[63&r];return t%3===1?(r=n[t-1],a[o]=i[r>>2],a[o+1]=i[r<<4&63],a[o+2]=61,a[o+3]=61):t%3===2&&(r=(n[t-2]<<8)+n[t-1],a[o]=i[r>>10],a[o+1]=i[r>>4&63],a[o+2]=i[r<<2&63],a[o+3]=61),new TextDecoder('ascii').decode(a)};"
            + "var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();"
            + "xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';"
            + "xhr.onload = function(){ callback(toBase64(xhr.response)) };"
            + "xhr.onerror = function(){ callback(xhr.status) };"
            + "xhr.open('GET','"+ uri +"');"
            + "xhr.send();";

       JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
       String result = (jsExecutor.executeAsyncScript(script, uri)).toString();
       return result;
    }
   ```

Not getting any error with this method but the value that I am getting is incorrect.

Expected value when the QR code is scanned from a mobile device: `ecfe09ff-ca31-4e16-9550-82da38a45966`

Value after running this code: `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`

Please help. I have searched everywhere and couldn't find a single solution to read a QR code. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have found a way to scan a QR code if the image src attribute has a blob url. I'm posting this answer for someone who might be stuck where I was and scratched my head.
So the solution is to combine the two methods that I have tried above.

First you need to take the URL and use the Javascript injection to get a byte array from your URL.

```
private String getBytesBase64FromBlobURI(String uri) {
    String script = " "
         + "var uri = arguments[0];"
         + "var callback = arguments[1];"
         + "var toBase64 = function(buffer){for(var r,n=new Uint8Array(buffer),t=n.length,a=new Uint8Array(4*Math.ceil(t/3)),i=new Uint8Array(64),o=0,c=0;64>c;++c)i[c]='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'.charCodeAt(c);for(c=0;t-t%3>c;c+=3,o+=4)r=n[c]<<16|n[c+1]<<8|n[c+2],a[o]=i[r>>18],a[o+1]=i[r>>12&63],a[o+2]=i[r>>6&63],a[o+3]=i[63&r];return t%3===1?(r=n[t-1],a[o]=i[r>>2],a[o+1]=i[r<<4&63],a[o+2]=61,a[o+3]=61):t%3===2&&(r=(n[t-2]<<8)+n[t-1],a[o]=i[r>>10],a[o+1]=i[r>>4&63],a[o+2]=i[r<<2&63],a[o+3]=61),new TextDecoder('ascii').decode(a)};"
         + "var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();"
         + "xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';"
         + "xhr.onload = function(){ callback(toBase64(xhr.response)) };"
         + "xhr.onerror = function(){ callback(xhr.status) };"
         + "xhr.open('GET','"+ uri +"');"
         + "xhr.send();";

    JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    String result = (jsExecutor.executeAsyncScript(script, uri)).toString();
    return Base64.decodeBase64(result);
}
```

This function will return a byte array and you will need to decode it using the ZXing library.

```
private String decodeQRCode(byte[] qrCodeImage) throws IOException, NotFoundException {
    Result result = null;
    BufferedImage bufferedImage;
    bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(qrCodeImage));        
        
    LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(bufferedImage);
    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
    result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap);
        
    return result.getText();
}
```

Now this function will return the actual value of the QR code.